# Jenkins perform claim via rest api or groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

We need to set the claim remotely or as a post-build-action in jenkins. Is this even possible?

This doesn't work, or does nothing. Groovy post build:

> ```
> println("Claim job of $manager.build.project.name")
> ClaimBuildAction action = manager.build.getAction(hudson.plugins.claim.ClaimBuildAction.class);
> action.claim("user2", "reason", "user1", true);
> ```

I checked the testing for ClaimBuildPlugin, but looked a bit dirty to use HtmlForm to create a Claim.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/claim-plugin/blob/master/src/test/java/hudson/plugins/claim/ClaimTest.java

Comment: The BFA plugin did this https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer , so it shall be possible

Comment: @LarryCai: Maybe I'm missing your point Larry, but I see no reference to the ClaimPlugin in that repo. I think "Build Failure Analyser" have it's on implementations of something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the claim plugin implements a *post-build action*, **you must ensure two things**:

1. Add the "Allow broken build claiming" post-build action
2. Add your groovy post-build script *after* that

Here's a screenshot of a working configuration:

[image]

Comment: Great thanks! Was it also needed, which I didn't have during testing is an actual build-step. That was what I was missing.

Comment: Oh yes -- if it aint broken then you can't claim it : )